Call Chat-GPT Assistant using Google Apps Script
I wrote a small Google Apps Script that basically calls a trained Chat-GPT Playground Assistant to answer my query.  The code is working perfectly when using it for example with a default model such as:
gpt-3.5-turbo

The problem is that I keep getting the error that my specific model is not recognized. However, as far as I can find in the documentation this should be working.
Here is the code:
Please note that I changed the values of API key and assistant ID so you can't recognize it anymore.
const API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
const API_URL = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'; // Use the correct endpoint for your model

function callGPT(prompt) {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      model: 'asst_XXXXXX', // Specify your custom model ID here
      // model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [
        { role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' }, // Initial system message to set the context
        { role: 'user', content: prompt } // The user prompt
      ],
      max_tokens: 100  // Adjust as needed
    })
  });

  const json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return json.choices[0].message.content.trim(); // Adjust based on your API's response format
}

function GPTResponse(prompt) {
  return callGPT(prompt);
}

function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('GPT')
    .addItem('Get GPT Response', 'showPromptDialog')
    .addToUi();
}

function showPromptDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = ui.prompt('Enter your prompt:');
  
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    const prompt = response.getResponseText();
    const result = callGPT(prompt);
    ui.alert('GPT Response:', result, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

Can someone please explain why this is still not working?
Error:
Exception: Request failed for https://api.openai.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {
    "error": {
        "message": "The model `asst_XXXXX` does not exist or you do not have access to it.",
        "type": "i... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
callGPT @ Code.gs:5

I already looked into the following things but this doesn't seem to be the problem:
I thought the endpoint 'api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions' may be off for using assistants but this seems correct.
I already made a 100% sure that I am using the correct Assistant ID
I thought maybe V1 doesn't support using Assistant ID as model but this seems to be the case.
Maybe I should place the Assistant ID in the place of 'model: ' however, this also seems to be correct.
I was expecting it to run when calling the function in a Google Spreadsheet cell.

The code doesn't look to be using the right OpenAI Assistant API. I think that you should take some steps back and read thoroughly https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/overview.
From the above link, here are the section headings

Step 1: Create an Assistant
Step 2: Create a Thread
Step 3: Add a Message to the Thread
Step 4: Create a Run

If you prefer to go directly to the API references, go to  https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants
